# Load different Business Catalyst stylesheet if LoggedIn

Tags: conditional-statements, business-catalyst

In Business Catalyst, is there a conditional statement that allows loading a different stylesheet based on whether or not a user is logged-in? 
Changing style using GetElementById does not work as there are multiple system-generated elements that need to be re-styled. I have tried GetElementByClassName, but this does not work. I thought perhaps by loading a completely separate stylesheet based on logged-in status might work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to insert this tag:

```
    {module_isloggedin}
```

Anywhere you want... for example in your ID/class syntax:

```
    id="menu_{module_isloggedin}"  or class="menu_{module_isloggedin}"
```

Or you should be able to even do something like:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login-{module_isloggedin}.css">
```

which will resolve to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login-1.css">
```

if the user is logged in and

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login-0.css">
```

if the user is not logged in...

Try that out... :)